# How to bind the data from database to grid using dt.select dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

Below is the method that i used to display records based on the conditions.
I have so many rows inserted in database and the data should be displayed in such a way that:

- for the first grid i need to bind from A00-B99
- for the second grid bind from c00-d49
- for the third grid bind from d50-d89
- for the fourth grid bind from E00-E89

like that i have so many grids that which i should bind the data but it is not working.

```
  public void BindGrid()
        {

            string query = "select * from tablename";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            Session["dt1"] = dt;
            DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];
            DataRow[] dr = dt2.Select("Text >='A%' AND Text >='B%' OR Text ='C%'");
            DataTable Newdt = dr.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
            grd1.DataSource = Newdt;
            grd1.DataBind();

        }
```

What happens is the data that starts with A and B in the text column gets eliminated and from c to z gets binded to my first grid but the series with A and B should get binded to first grid and series C and D should get binded to second grid ie(c00-d49) and the series that are remaining in D should get binded to third grid(ie D50-D89) and series E should get binded to fourth grid(ie E00-E89) like that it should be done.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you filter ranges out of your initial DataTable and assign each range to a new DataTable. Here is an example, of course you will continue to query for your data, but I have built the data manually for demonstration. Also [shared as LinqPad Query](http://share.linqpad.net/39xers.linq)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", Type.GetType("System.String")));

DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "A00";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "B50";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "B99";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "c00";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "c30";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "c49";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "c50";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "d59";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "d50";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "d60";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "d89";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "E00";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "E50";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "E89";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "E90";
dt.Rows.Add(r);

var range1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where (d => d[0].ToString().CompareTo("A") >= 0 && d[0].ToString().CompareTo("B99") <= 0);
DataTable TableRange1 = range1.CopyToDataTable();

var range2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where (d => d[0].ToString().CompareTo("c00") >= 0 && d[0].ToString().CompareTo("d49") <= 0);
DataTable TableRange2 = range2.CopyToDataTable();

var range3 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where (d => d[0].ToString().CompareTo("E00") >= 0 && d[0].ToString().CompareTo("E89") <= 0);
DataTable TableRange3 = range3.CopyToDataTable();
```